# не работает постраничная навигация

Tags: навигация

Проблема вот в чем: функция правильно считает количество товаров, правильно разбивает их на количество страниц (например по 3 товара на странице). Но при переходе на страницу 2 или 3 отображаются те же самые товары, хотя в URL пишет .....?page2
Переменная $category получается из GET по ссылке с предыдущей страницы.
Полный url выглядит так: http://domen.com/category/smesiteli?page=2
category это файл, который получает название из .htaccess вот строка RewriteRule ^category/([a-z0-9-]+)?$ view_katalog.php?category=$1 [L]

```
<?php
    include("include/db_connect.php");
    $category = clear_string($_GET["category"]);
?>
<?php  
$num = 3; 
$page = $_GET['page']; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM domik_db WHERE category='$category'"); 
$posts = mysql_result($result, 0); 
$total = intval(($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;  
$page = intval($page); 
if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1; 
  if($page > $total) $page = $total; 
$start = $page * $num - $num;  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM domik_db WHERE category='$category' LIMIT $start, $num");  
while ( $postrow[] = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
?> 
 <?php 
echo "<table>"; 
for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) 
{ 
 echo "<tr>
         <td>".$postrow[$i]['name']."</td>
         <td>".$postrow[$i]['id']."</td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan=\"2\">".$postrow[$i]['text']."</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 
?> 
 <?php  
if ($page != 1) $pervpage = '<a href= ./'.$category.'?page=1><<</a> 
                               <a href= ./'.$category.'?page='. ($page - 1) .'><</a> '; 
if ($page != $total) $nextpage = ' <a href= ./'.$category.'?page='. ($page + 1) .'>></a> 
                                   <a href= ./'.$category.'?page=' .$total. '>>></a>'; 

if($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = ' <a href= ./'.$category.'?page='. ($page - 2) .'>'. ($page - 2) .'</a> | '; 
if($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<a href= ./'.$category.'?page='. ($page - 1) .'>'. ($page - 1) .'</a> | '; 
if($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = ' | <a href= ./'.$category.'?page='. ($page + 2) .'>'. ($page + 2) .'</a>'; 
if($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = ' | <a href= ./'.$category.'?page='. ($page + 1) .'>'. ($page + 1) .'</a>';

echo $pervpage.$page2left.$page1left.'<b>'.$page.'</b>'.$page1right.$page2right.$nextpage; 

?>
```

Comment: Сделайте перед запросом `var_dump($start); var_dump($category);`. Так же, выведите запрос в отдельную переменную `$sql`, и покажите, `var_dump($sql);`

Comment: А как вы это дебажили вообще?

Comment: var_dump($start); возвращает int (0)

Comment: var_dump($category); возвращает string (9) "smesiteli"

Comment: var_dump($start); возвращает int (0) т.е при переходе на другую страницу он не понимает откуда начинать и начинает с начала, а как это исправить?

Comment: У вас `page` не пробрасывается в скрипт. Ошибка в .htaccess. И должно быть не `?page2`, а `?page=2`

Comment: Alexander Grushko спасибо за помощь!!! Проблему решил у меня небыло написано в конце QSA. Может кому пригодится правильная строка выглядит так: RewriteRule ^category/([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ view_katalog.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: На счет "должно быть не ?page2, а ?page=2" у меня так и было, я ошибся задавая вопрос.